# Design pattern Adapter in Javascript for cross platform HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am developing a cross platform HTML5 app that will be wrapped in Android, in Windows 8, in iOS and there will be also a web version

Since every platform has different ways of accessing dom, or accessing storage, or accessing cameras, my idea was to create a function like:

```
function CameraAdapter() {
  if (windows8) {return Windows8.Camera}
  else if (android) ..
}
```

And from [Addyosmani book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#wrapperpatternjquery):

> The Adapter Pattern translates an interface for an object or class
>   into an interface compatible with a specific system.

In terms of Design pattern, is it considered to be a Factory? and Adapter? How do I write this class to be "in the standard" of OOP design patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is somewhat close to the Factory pattern, though it has some differences with it. You can find an example of the standard factory pattern [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript) and see the differences by yourself. In your code, you are simply encapsulating your object creation inside a method.

Having said that, don't just use patterns because you want to as it tends to lead to poor and complex application architecture. Use the most simple solution which solves your problem at hand. If that problem and the solution matches with a standard pattern, you should then rafactor your code to implement that pattern. This approach is called refactoring into patterns, and is the right way to use the standard design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you are implementing is a factory method? You can encapsulate the creation of your object using the factory method and then implement a common interface/adapter pattern for each of your different classes returned by your factory method.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use an existing tool like http://modernizr.com/ to detect features? Also, if you use a javascript framework (for e.g jquery UI/mobile, angular js etc) you don't have to do anything device specific. The framework does the heavy lifting for you.